# Use of key file in Google Secret Manager

Tags: java, maven, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

Currently I am working on a Java Maven Project and was trying to integrate Google Secret Manager in my application. I need to set up authentication. I have generated the keyfile (service-account-file.json). Now I need to use it for authentication.

I am not able to find a way where to store this file and how to use it in my project using Java code. In the docs it is written ***Provide authentication credentials to your application code by setting the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.*** This is done using command line. I need to do the same using Java code in my project.

Proper documentation of creating and accessing and managing the secrets is present but couldn't find one for authentication.

https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries#create-service-account-gcloud

Comment: Will your java app run on GCP?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes

Comment: If your app run on Google Cloud platform, you don't need a service account key file (in the secret manager or not). You can leverage the ADC and the metadata server.

Answer (score 2):

Java things are generally ran using the command line/a terminal, in one way or another (either by you, or by an IDE).

You just need to export that environment variable in the same terminal where the java commands are ran. If you run your java code via some other program like an IDE, then the IDE will execute the commands for you, so just look up in the IDE documentation where you can set the environment variables that they should use.

That being said, you can also not use the env variable and use the path to a json file with credentials, eg for cloud storage:

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code

Other client libraries have similar methods (usually also a `setCredentials()` method on the Builder class) to do the same.